# jQuery get href initial value once before it changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append, href

In my application I have an ajax call, and on success it appends some data to an existing links href.

This works great. The issue is, If I want to run the ajax call again and on success, append some different data, it is taking the href value + the new value from the previous ajax call, and than adding the new data after that.

I want it to add the data to the inital href value, before it was appended.

Below is my code:
(I have the sample sample value being appended each time for testing purposes)

```
        //get next page link value, so we can add filter to url
    var next_link = $("a.next").attr("href");

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_calls.php",
        data: "instrument="+selected.val()+"&filter=true",
        success: function(listing){$("#listings").html(listing);

$("a.next").attr("href", next_link + '&field=x');

},
        error: function(){alert(3);$("#error").text("Could not retrieve posts").fadeIn(300).delay(900).fadeOut(300)}
    });
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using jQuery's [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method?

```
$('#change').click(function(){
    var newData = Math.random() * 1000; // fake new data
    $('a').each(function(i,e){
        var oldHref = $(this).data('oldHref');
        if (!oldHref){
            var oldHref = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).data('oldHref',oldHref);
        }
        $(this).attr('href',oldHref + '#' + newData);
    });
});

<a href="http://google.com">Hello, world!</a><br />
<input type="button" id="change" value="Change HREF" />
```

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/Whc5z/)**

Store the old value in a data element, then reference before each new change.

Comment: Thanks. This does make sense. I will need to look at the example more to understand how to implement this.

Comment: @levi: If you have any questions just post them as a comment to this answer and I'll do my best to explain. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I got it working using your code, I just need to spend some time going through it so I can fully wrap my head around it lol. (yes noob)